# Shell script: How to prepend env variable with prefix only if environment variable is defined?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, zsh

Given `command` that requires flag `--flag`. We want to insert this flag only when the value of the flag is provided as environment variable `VALUE`.

I tried the following:

```bash
echo "command ${X+--flag ${VALUE}}"
```

```bash
VALUE=1
echo "command ${X+--flag ${VALUE}}"'
```

References:

- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Answer (score 4):

```bash
command ${VALUE:+--flag "$VALUE"}
```

This runs `command` with the option `--flag` and its option-argument `"$VALUE"` if the variable `VALUE` is defined and non-empty.  If the variable is empty or undefined, it runs `command` without arguments.

In the `zsh` shell, which does not perform word-splitting on unquoted expansions, you will have to set the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` shell option (`setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT`), run the shell in `sh` compatibility mode (`zsh --emulate sh`), or use

```bash
command ${=VALUE:+--flag "$VALUE"}
```

... to ensure that `--flag` and `"$VALUE"` are passed as two separate arguments when `VALUE` is set to a non-empty value.

Remove the `:` in the parameter substitution if you want the `--flag` option added when `VALUE` is defined but empty.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work in zsh when not in sh emulation (`shwordsplit` option enabled) in that it passes one argument with an embedded space. `command ${VALUE+--flag} ${VALUE+"$VALUE"}` for code compatible to all.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. This is what greatly confused me! What is the closest syntax that is portable to zsh?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I hope I addressed that now.

Comment: You don't want the `:` as the OP didn't specify that the empty string should be handled specially.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I do, if I want to trigger the expansion only on non-empty values of `$VALUE`. I'll add a note.

Comment: `zsh -c 'echo command ${=param:+"--flag ${param}"}; param=1; echo command ${=param:+"--flag ${param}"}'` - works, but bash is not happy about `=` `bash -c 'echo command ${=param:+"--flag ${param}"}` returns `bash: ${=param:+"--flag ${param}"}: bad substitution` Is there any way to make this truly portable?

Comment: @AB I'm a bit confused. Don't you know what language you're writing in? I wouldn't write a Perl program to be executable by Python or vice versa. Why try to write polyglot code in shell scripts? You could use `sh` syntax (the first command in my answer) and then run with `zsh --emulate sh` if you find yourself using `zsh`. Note that the `zsh` shell was not written with `sh`-compatibility in mind.

Comment: I see and agree with your point re: Perl. Same time as an OSS author, I'm trying to ensure that my code is reusable where possible.

Comment: @AB Then write for the `sh` shell, and run all shells in `sh` compatibility mode, if possible.